# didSelectRowAtIndexPath arbitrary called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UIViewController which contains a UITableView. Everything is in place :datasource, delegate, wired everything in IB. didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called all the time. I have no transparent views or buttons that would cover the rows I touch.
Any ideas why this is happening?

No fancy things in didSelect:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"IT WORKS");
}
```

Comment: Check the attributes inspector in IB, did you set "Selection" to Single / Multiple selection? If yes, show your didSelectRowAtIndexPath code.

Comment: I put there just an NSLog to see if it's called. One particular thing about this viewcontroller is that I also have a webview in it and I switch from it to tableview and back. I keep a reference of the scrollview which belongs to webview. then I set that property's delegate si I can track when webview is dragged. I suspect this creates all th weirdness

Comment: are you overlaying the tableview and webview? and by switching, do you mean one view is hidden by the other?

Comment: Does the row select when you touch the label of the cell? Rather than the other part of the cell. Try touching the far left hand side

Comment: when one is hidden the other is shown. it is not that i can't touch the table. the selection works, but most of the time didselect is not called.

Comment: the row select all the time, wherever i touch it. let me give you one more detail: if I touch a row and then another it starts working.also the first row which didnt work will work now. at the same time, when I have just one row it selects but didSelect is not called at all.

Comment: @AlexTau, this last comment was an important clue but you left it out in your OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! You used did**De**selectRowAtIndexPath instead of didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: This happens if we just over dependent on any automatic facility :0